# CSS Partially Filled Stars and Spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm using HTML and CSS to show a star rating based on a percentage.  I'm trying to get that percentage to match the percentage of the stars filled.

I have it close, but when I add the 'letter-spacing' and 'padding-left' CSS to make it look better on my web page, the percentage of the filled area changes.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.score {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #FFF;
}

.score::before,
.score span::before {
  content: "✰✰✰✰✰";
  display: block;
}

.score span {
  color: #E6DB74;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scorePadded {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.scorePadded::before,
.scorePadded span::before {
  content: "✰✰✰✰✰";
  display: block;
}

.scorePadded span {
  color: #E6DB74;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="score"><span style="width: 68.0%"></span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="scorePadded"><span style="width: 68.0%"></span></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to make the bottom stars (with the spacing) filled to the same percentage as the top stars (which I believe is correctly showing a 68% fill), but the spacing isn't allowing that.

Comment: You'll need some more complex logic here other than just percentage. The stars in your first example add up to a perfect 100%, so 68% means "68% of the stars are filled". Each star represents 20% of the total width.  In your spaced example, each star represents approximately 12% of the total width.

Comment: Where does the percentage come from? If it's from JavaScript, you can implement a more complex formula to determine the stars filled. However if you're simply manually entering the value, you'll need to do some manual math.

Comment: I'm using jekyll, which I'm feeding in ratings.  So, my rating could be 3.8 out of 5 stars.  So my logic looks like this in jekyll: <span class="score"><span style="width: {{ item.my-rating |divided_by:5.0 |times:100 }}%"></span></span>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gaps make this a bit more complex than a simple percentage. I don't believe there's a CSS solution that can account for the gaps, so that the fill is applied explicitly to the stars themselves.

That said, with a bit of math, you could apply the correct width with a formula.

As I see it, you need to take your rating and multiply it by the width of a star. This tells us how much to fill, in pixels. E.g., `rating * starWidth`, where rating is out of `5`.

You then need to add for each gap. The amount of gaps the score crosses can be expressed as `Math.floor(rating)`. To get the width in pixels, it's `Math.floor(rating) * gapSize`. This is how many pixels we have to add to account for the large gaps, ensuring that when we get to one, we start filling the next star instead of the gap between them.

By adding the fill width and the gap width, you get this:

```
totalWidthInPixels = (rating * starWidth) + (gaps * gapSize);
```

Seeing as you mentioned you're calculating this percentage using Jekyll, and I don't know anything about Jekyll, I'll let you fill in that part.

A demonstration of the formula can be seen below.

```js
const span1 = document.getElementById("score");
const span2 = document.getElementById("scorePadded");

const rating = parseFloat(prompt("Enter rating between 0-5"));
const starWidth = span1.offsetWidth / 5.0;
const gapSize = (span2.offsetWidth - span1.offsetWidth - 5) / 5.0;
const gaps = Math.floor(rating);

const width = (rating * starWidth) + (gaps * gapSize);

span1.style.width = `${(rating/5) * 100}%`;
span2.style.width = `${width}px`;

console.log("star width: ", starWidth);
console.log("gap size: ", gapSize);
console.log("fill width: ", width);
```

```css
.score {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #FFF;
}

.score::before,
.score span::before {
  content: "✰✰✰✰✰";
  display: block;
}

.score span {
  color: #E6DB74;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scorePadded {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.scorePadded::before,
.scorePadded span::before {
  content: "✰✰✰✰✰";
  display: block;
}

.scorePadded span {
  color: #E6DB74;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="score"><span id="score"></span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="scorePadded"><span id="scorePadded"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What about decimal values? If I enter 3.5 the rating is not the same on both of the stars. Completely filling the stars is an easy job for an integer

Comment: No, in the first row, the last star is filled as half and in the row below the last one is not filled

Comment: Looks perfect from my end

Comment: In Firefox 68.0 (64-bit) on OSX, 3.4 results in 4 stars fully coloured.

Comment: Nice solution!!